# Vector of base type, cant add derived type to vector

Tags: c++

I have a class that inherits from IEffect

```
class EffectPosition3NormalColor : public IEffect
{
    //code
}
```

I then create a vector of IEffect*

```
vector<IEffect*> Effects;
```

Trying to add elements to this vector

```
Effects.push_back(new Position3NormalColor());
```

fails with the following error message

```
cannot convert from 'Position3NormalColor *' to 'IEffect *'
```

How would i fix this?

Comment: Why would you expect it to work? There's nothing in what you have shown that suggests it should.

Comment: Is it a typo or do you mean 'new EffectPosition3NormalColor()'?

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Position3NormalColor` apparently isn't publicly derived from `IEffect`.

Note that you only posted the code for `EffectPosition3NormalColor`, not `Position3NormalColor`.